# Spark List scrolling by mouse position

Tags: apache-flex, list, scroll, mouse

```
<s:List xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

        mouseOver="scroller_mouseOver(event)" 
        height="308" width="110">
```

As seen above, I have a Spark List with the MouseOver event:

```
protected function scroller_mouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void { 
   CursorManager.removeAllCursors();      // Remove all previous Cursors
   if (mouseX > 24 && mouseX < 143) {
     if (mouseY > 220) {
          CursorManager.setCursor(downCursorSymbol);    // Down Cursor
     } else if (mouseY < 87) {
          CursorManager.setCursor(upCursorSymbol);     // Up Cursor
     }
     // Scroll as its Mouse Overed
     this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scrollViaY);
     }
}

private function scrollViaY(e:Event):void {
   if (mouseX > 24 && mouseX < 143) {
     if (mouseY > 220) {
     this.layout.verticalScrollPosition += (mouseY - 220)*0.5; 
     }
     else if (mouseY < 87) {
     this.layout.verticalScrollPosition += (mouseY -86)*0.5; 
     }
   }
}
```

The following picture describes the area I would like to track hovering.
[image: List Upper & Lower hover tracking to scroll]

**The Problem:** When I hover the upper (red) part of the List (I would like to have the List scroll downward, the higher the mouse position is, the faster it should scroll). Similarly, If the mouse hovers over the bottom (red) part, the List scrolls upwards, and the lower the mouse is hovered, the faster the list would scroll. The current code does work - Though, the trace outs make it obvious that:
this.layout.verticalScrollPosition += (mouseY - 220)*0.5;
or 
this.layout.verticalScrollPosition += (mouseY -86)*0.5;
...are giving jumping effects, is there a way to make these values change more linearly or smoother?

I created an AnimateProperty, but that works well only if I would like to scroll to a selectedIndex, In this case, I would like the scroller to keep scrolling linearly as the mouse is hovered to a particular red area, and increase in speed when I scroll to either extremity.

**The Objective:** While the mouse is over the Bottom (red part )of the List, the verticalScrollPosition scrolls faster as it gets farther than the center of the ticket list... yet there is jumping effect going on, I suppose due to the EnterFrame. the Same with Upper Part... the higher the cursor is, the faster the List should scroll.

I feel this is a common problem to Flash CSx developers.

Comment: soooo.. your problem is.. the slight jittering?

Comment: In short yes, even though I doubt my code is optimized... the EnterFrame is skewing the next position of the VerticalScroller. I've seen this in many swf files, though I was curious on how I should go about developing it.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I've edited the Question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something similar, except it was a horizontal scrolling list, and also I used a scroll left/right buttons on the sides of the list, the mouse_over effect is triggered by the buttons, not the list (but this shouldn't be an impediment when adapting the code).

To do the actual scrolling, I used an animate effect which targeted the list's layout, and more specifically, the layout's `horizontalScrollPosition`. This it what the MXML code looks like:

```
<s:Animate id="scrollAnimation" target="{listLayout}">
    <s:easer>
        <s:Linear easeInFraction="0" easeOutFraction="0" />
    </s:easer>

    <s:SimpleMotionPath id="scrollMotionPath" property="horizontalScrollPosition" />
</s:Animate>
```

That `easer` is necessary because animate effect usually have 3 motion stages (acceleration, uniform motion and deceleration), so by default you would get a wavy scrolling motion.
I used RobotLeft for that project, so the view is mediated like this:

When the mediator is registered, add the scroll button listeners:

```
viewComponent.scrollLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onScrollLeft);
viewComponent.scrollRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onScrollRight);
viewComponent.scrollLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onScrollOut);
viewComponent.scrollRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onScrollOut);
```

We also need to add a listener so we can tell when the scrolling effect finished, because we might need to replay it:

```
viewComponent.scrollEffect.addEventListener(EffectEvent.EFFECT_END, onScrollEnd);
```

We can now implement the scrolling method. Since the view is mediated, we have access to the scroll effect, we can reference it here (and also the path). This what the method looks like:

```
private function scrollOnlineFriendsList(scrollBy:int):void
{
    // Set the scrollBy value and play the scrolling effect
    viewComponent.scrollMotionPath.valueBy = scrollBy;
    viewComponent.scrollEffect.play();

    // Store the scrollBy value in case the effect will need to be replayed,
    // if the mouse over event is still over the scrolling button/area
    this.scrollBy = scrollBy;

    canKeepScrolling = true;
}
```

Finally, the handlers:

```
private function onScrollLeft(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollOnlineFriendsList(-33);
}

private function onScrollRight(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    scrollOnlineFriendsList(33);
}

private function onScrollOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    canKeepScrolling = false;

    // If you would like the effect to continue playing
    // until it finishes the current scrolling operation,
    // once the mouse is no longer over a scroll button,
    // just comment this line
    viewComponent.scrollEffect.stop();
}

private function onScrollEnd(event:EffectEvent):void
{
    // When the scroll effect has finished playing,
    // if the mouse is still over the scroll button/area,
    // replay the effect
    if (canKeepScrolling)
        scrollOnlineFriendsList(scrollBy);
}
```